# NSManagedObject: isUpdated and changedValues discrepancy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I have a Core Data entity class that subclasses NSManagedObject.

I want to update the entity's attribute with a last modif. timestamp, so I'm implementing its `willSave` method.

I found out that when the method is called, `isUpdated` returns TRUE but `changedValues` is empty (same for `changedValuesForCurrentEvent`).

Can you explain me how is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: do you have some default values you set to the object again?
the values wouldn't change, but your object is "marked" as updated

Answer (score 2):

The state method `isUpdated` is set to `YES` when any property that causes KVO notifications is updated, so re-setting a property to it's current value will cause `isUpdated` to be set to `YES`.

`changedValues` returns the properties that have *actually* been changed. Perhaps a category method like this would help:

```
- (BOOL) isActuallyUpdated
{
    return self.changedValues.count > 0
}
```